Memory Leak in SSR with Webpack and Express
Having launched the process on localhost, every time I open a new tab on the start page of my application, my Heap Memory increases. This happens until its size exceeds 4GB. After that, in the console I see
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
After making snapshots of Heap Memory, I see that a certain string is accumulating in memory, which is the content of the file that is located in my server-build/index.js. Is this normal behavior or not? If not, how can I fix it?
Heap screenshot
I tried to change the webpack configuration, but nothing helped.

Is this normal behavior: I would say it is not intended behaviour. As long as you are not trying to launch GTA in browser, you probably have an error in the code, most likely a cyclic one.
